# MQTT Keep Alive byte format

Tags: byte, mqtt

The [MQTT 3.1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.pdf) documentation is very clear and helpful, however I am having trouble understanding the meaning of one section regarding the Keep Alive byte structure in the connect message.

The documentation states:

> The Keep Alive is a time interval measured in seconds. Expressed as a 16-bit word, it is the maximum time interval that is permitted to elapse between the point at which the Client finishes transmitting one Control Packet and the point it starts sending the next.

And gives an example of a keep alive payload:

1. Keep Alive MSB (0)  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2. Keep Alive LSB (10) 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

I have interpreted this to represent a keep alive interval of 10 seconds, as the interval is given in seconds and that makes the most sense. However I'm not sure how you would represent longer intervals of, for example, 10 minutes.

Finally, would the maximum keep alive interval of 65535 seconds (~18 hours) be represented by these bytes

1. Keep Alive MSB (255) 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2. Keep Alive LSB (255) 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

2^16=65536 seconds 65536/60 = 1092.27 minutes 1092.27/60 = 18.20 hours

0.20hour*60 = 12minutes y 0.27min*60  = 16.2sec

result: 18 hours,12minutes, 16sec

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes = 600 seconds

600 in binary -> 0000 0010 0101 1000

And yes 65535 is the largest number that can be represented by a 16bit binary field, but there are very few situations where an 18 hour keep alive interval would make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but why would an 18 hour keep alive interval not make sense? If you are waiting for messages in an IoT application, having to ping every 18 hours as opposed to every 10 minutes would be far more efficient.

Comment: Because the timeout for a TCP connection is 15mins so the device will have to wake up to send sync/ack packets anyway. Also the keep alive period is how a broker know the device is alive, I can't think of a situation where you want to wait that long to know the device is not working makes sense